# Send an email when video encoding ends?

Tags: php, email, ffmpeg

I want to send an email to user when ffmpeg encoding process ends.

How can I understand that his/her video is ready?

Comment: How are you converting the video? Your question is vague to the point that it can't be answered in it's current state

Comment: Monitor the ffmpeg process, check for errors or successful conversion, send email via your preferred route.

Comment: Wrapping the encoding call by a shell script that send a mail at the end ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799326/how-to-check-if-ffmpeg-is-done-encoding-a-video-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FAM](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fam.php), which can be used for monitoring directory changes. I suspect that you can use [fam_monitor_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fam-monitor-file.php). It will give you one event when the file is initially created by the encoder, and a second once it's done writing (encoding).